# Search efficient in a large mysql database (LIKE functionality)

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I'm starting to get a large database with about 10 million rows in one table that I'm joining with another table. When searching in the large table I'm searching for a title (varchar) or an article number (varchar).

At the moment I'm using "%LIKE%" queries but they are starting to get really slow (Sometimes a couple of seconds).

Can I search faster for a title or an article number in this table without losing the "%LIKE%" functionality?

I´ve been looking at stuff like sphinx and solr but I would like to know if it´s possible to solve with pure mysql?

Is it possible to use any kind of partition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [full text search in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE MATCH (title,body)
AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Comment: Fulltext search wont give me the same behavior as LIKE.